# Radius of convergence: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!x^n}{100^n}$

Tags: power-series

I'm having some trouble understanding why the following power series interval of convergences is equal to 0.

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!x^n}{100^n}$$

According to my calculation, my answer is equal to $-100 < x < 100$
since I end up with:
$|x/100| < 1$

I did it with the ratio test.

Can somebody explain to me why it equal to $0$?
Thank you

Comment: Where did the $n!$ go?

Comment: It equals to infinit

Comment: You have not answered my question: what did you do to it?

Comment: Seriously, nothing, I just decided to dismiss it, but then the answer below made me understand that I shouldn't have since that it is the reason why it equals to 0 (1/infinity).

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n:=\frac{n!x^n}{100^n}$. Then for all $x\neq 0$ we have $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{(n+1)|x|}{100}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty.$$
Factorials beat powers!

Comment: You don't need $x$ to determine the radius of convergence

Comment: OK, so all that multiplied by infinity equal to infinity, then 1/ifinity = 0 right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're taking reciprocal. The sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges for $x\neq 0$ by the ratio test (seeing my above computation). See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: @Bernard I was just using the ratio test on the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: School homework restrictions, we only learned the ration test so far. I know there are many other tests, but it is the only one we learned. Else, I just want to thank you for making me realising it

Comment: But I am using the ratio test.

Comment: Yes, but it is wall known that for power series it is enough to apply this test on the coefficients (same  for the root test).